# Select documents with some non unique attribute in mongo / mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, database

I have a collection called Shippers and these documents have email addresses. Each entity also has a phone number.

There are some scenarios where several documents in my collection have the same email address, but only some have a specified phone number. I want to select the documents that contain the same email address as some other document, but that DONT have a phone number specified. Something like this I imagine:

```
Shipper.where('this.phone_number = nil AND this.email = Shipper.email')
```

I know I can compare things by doing this.attribute1 = this.attribute2, but this only compares the same document to itself. I want to compare the email on one document to all other documents of my collection, as above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `group_by`? For example,

`Shipper.where(phone_number: nil).group_by(&:email)`

Comment: I want to select documents iff their email is the same as another document's email. Wont this also return documents which dont meet this condition?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
Shipper.distinct(:email).each { |email_address|
  Shipper.where(:phone_number => nil).where(:email => email_address).each { |shipper|
    # do whatever you want with shipper document.
  }
}
```

This first gets each unique email address, then for each of them gives you all shipper records with empty phone numbers.

Note: not tested, may have mistakes.